# Flutter Redux Navigation library import error

Tags: flutter, redux, flutter-redux

I have been developing application and one of the libraries I have used was Flutter Redux Navigation. Everything was working fine, until recently, when I started getting following error

```
../../lib/src/navigation_middleware.dart:3:1: Error: 'NavigationDestination' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/navigation_bar.dart' and 'package:flutter_redux_navigation/src/navigation_destination.dart'.
import 'package:flutter_redux_navigation/src/navigation_destination.dart';
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../lib/src/navigation_middleware.dart:35:26: Error: 'NavigationDestination' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/navigation_bar.dart' and 'package:flutter_redux_navigation/src/navigation_destination.dart'.
          this._setState(NavigationDestination(
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../lib/src/navigation_middleware.dart:55:26: Error: 'NavigationDestination' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/navigation_bar.dart' and 'package:flutter_redux_navigation/src/navigation_destination.dart'.
          this._setState(NavigationDestination(
```

I even tried to copy example project from their git, and got exactly same error. This is something in library, or perhaps some settings of my IDE? Please let me know if anyone encountered this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I have upgraded Flutter version from 2.5.1 to 2.8.0. The newest Flutter version contains upgraded Material library, which contains the method called `NavigationDestination`. Thus both, the library and Material design have the same name of the class, of course, resulting in error.